# Xamarin PCL and Microsoft.Net.Http for HttpClient is this supported on Android AND iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There seem to be a lot of conflicting statements out there with regard to my question.  I have a PCL project that I have added the Microsoft.Net.Http package to in order to consume a WepAPI, will this work on both my Android and iOS app?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should be, but I think you have to use ModernHttpClient which is only supported on Android API level 5.0 and greater. At least the people i work with had to use modern http client libary in order to get it to work with ssl certificates.

Comment: @victor you are a bit wrong. ModernHttpClient works on all API's that Xamarin supports. It is the AndroidHttpHandler that Xamarin provides, which will only use OkHttp on Android 5.0 and up.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you choose a newer PCL profile, you don't even need to add the NuGet package and you can just use HttpClient directly.

To answer your question, yes this will work. Even with the HttpClientHandler's which Xamarin provides. It will also work with ModernHttpClient.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you for the feedback.  I will go with the option os choosing a new PCL profile and see if that works :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using a newer PCL profile"? I've updated pretty much everything (VS, nuget packages, etc.) and my project, which was created about 2 weeks ago (October 2017) does not support HttpClient. Meaning it does tell me that HttpClient does not exist.

Comment: Choose a PCL profile that has a better subset. Something like Profile 7. You could also choose to switch to .NET Standard instead.